# Understanding “um so schneller” in this Kafka sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, adjective, particle

What is the contribution of *um* and the comparative form of *schnell* to the meaning of this sentence in Kafka’s *Der Verschollene*?

> Und da das Ärgste ausgesprochen war, drängte alles andere **um** so schnell**er** nach, er sagte, ohne die geringste Lüge zu gebrauchen, Dinge, an die er gar nicht eigentlich vorher gedacht hatte.

Another way to put this question may be to ask how the sentence above is different from:

> Und da das Ärgste ausgesprochen war, drängte alles andere so schnell nach, er sagte, ohne die geringste Lüge zu gebrauchen, Dinge, an die er gar nicht eigentlich vorher gedacht hatte.

I can only come up with the following guess (by a blind, mechanical application of grammar and meaning):  *alles andere* came out faster (*schneller*) than *das Ärgste*, and the degree (*so*) by which that *Nachdrängen* was faster is not exactly but only approximately (*um*) as set out in the *er sagte* clause.

But this kind of precision seems out of place for the situation (we’re not measuring the speed of some projectile).  Maybe *um* + a comparative form of adverb has a special usage I am not aware of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*um so* is the old spelling of *[umso](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/umso)*.

The meaning of *umso* is:

> Konjunktion, die einen Komparativ verstärkt
>
> Conjunction that reinforces a comparative form of an adjective

Thus, in your example it means:
Because the worst [I assume: point of criticism] is already spoken aloud, it is **even more** easy to say other (smaller) [points of criticism], too. They burst out **even faster** and he says, without lying, even things he hadn't thought about before.

---

> Um so  in Verbindung mit je zeigt an, dass sich etwas proportional zu etwas anderem verändert, z.B.
> Je schneller der Wagen, umso größer die Gefahr
>
> The combination of *um so + je* shows the proportial change of two things, synomym to *desto*, e.g. The faster the car, the higher the danger

[References](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/umso)

Comment: Thanks!  So it's *all the more + adjective + for/because.*  Is *umso* a conjunction even in this context, and not an adverb?

Comment: If I understood wikipedia correctly,  yes.